# Can boot from SSD-drive, but Ubuntu installer can't find it

Tags: uefi, laptop, ssd, asus

Ubuntu installer can't find new SSD disk.

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a ASUS VivoBook, model R304LA with bios version 210. It has UEFI with secure boot and all that jazz, but I've managed to turn that off. Following this answer: [Get around UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252744/asus-x202e-vivobook-dual-boot-how-to-get-around-uefi-and-have-win8-ubuntu/565146#565146)

At this point I can see the disk in bios (efi) and also boot from the disk itself, which has a windows 10 install on it from another computer.

I can also boot from USB stick with Ubuntu live. But, when I do I can't find the drive.

For example: `sudo parted -l` shows nothing except the USB that I run Ubuntu Live on

Just to be clear, I'm not trying to dual-boot, I don't care about the contents of the drive. I just want Ubuntu to recognize it.

Any ideas as to how I can make ubuntu installer see the drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was actually the BIOS. I upgraded it from version 210 to 214, and voila! Disk was recognized in Ubuntu installer and installation ran smoothly.

A brief summary of the upgrading process. See pdf from ASUS for exact instructions [ASUS instruction PDF](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/S301LA/0409_E8276_A.pdf)

- Download the newest BIOS version
- Unzip the downloaded file and put it on a USB
- Restart the computer with USB inserted and enter BIOS.
- Enter the BIOS flashing meny in BIOS
- Locate your unzipped file on the USB and click start upgrade

Answer (score 1):

If the disk device (`/dev/sda` or whatever) doesn't show up in Ubuntu, but does show up in the firmware and in other OSes, then that most probably means that Ubuntu lacks drivers for the disk *controller chipset* on the *motherboard.* Don't bother checking with the disk manufacturer; it's almost certainly *not* a problem with the disk or SSD itself.

The usual solution for this problem is to wait for an updated kernel to be released. With Ubuntu, this basically means waiting for a new Ubuntu release. You didn't say what version of Ubuntu you're using, but you could try 15.10 (Wily), 14.04.3 (the latest in the Trusty series -- note that the ".3" at the end of the version is critical), or even a development version of 16.04 (Xenial).

In theory, you can compile your own kernel or use one from some other source. The trouble is twofold: First, most people lack the skills required to do this; and second, you've got to either integrate the kernel into the installer or install on another system and then swap in the new kernel, either of which complicates the install process.

There's a slim chance that adding kernel options will get the disk controller working; however, these options will depend very much on the chipset in question (which seems to be the Intel HM76, based on a check of the specs on ASUS' site). I don't know what these options might be.

Another option in some cases is to move the disk from one port on the motherboard to another one, since motherboards often have two SATA controllers, only one of which creates problems for Linux. This isn't likely to be an option for a laptop, though; I mention it only in the interests of providing a thorough answer, and in case somebody with a desktop system might read this in the future.

Comment: So far this seems to be the right answer :/
The Ubuntu version I was trying out with at first was 14.04.3. But since then I tried with latest version of Ubuntu and also Arch who uses 4.3.3-3 (I should probable try Arch testing though...) , however, none detects the drive. Everything indicates that what @Luke suggests won't work in this scenario either. But I'm gonna try it out, to be sure, before I accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to go about solving this issue, but if it were me, I'd just bypass it by installing Ubuntu to a hard drive and then cloning it over to the SSD using a program like Macrium Reflect. I did this and it worked okay, but I did have to run boot-repair to reconfigure GRUB. Best of luck to you!

Comment: I have thought of this, and will try it out. It's just a pain in the a** to open up this laptop. Worst case it is like Rod Smith suggests and this won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone checks this now. Just had an issue with Ubuntu not recognizing an SSD while it shows up just fine in windows.
I checked around and apparently, it's worth checking the drive interface controller settings: RAID / ACHI
On Windows, the port(connector) controller could be set to RAID for caching.